# How can I check if my AMP website version uses canonicals?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using AMP for WP on my WordPress website. I use it only for users that land on my page via Google. How can I check if the amp site uses canonicals to avoid duplicate content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the mobile page, add a link rel="canonical" tag pointing to the corresponding desktop URL.

https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls

Add the following to the non-AMP page:

And this to the AMP page:

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery